# Unable to create Opportunity in prod where as in sandbox working

Tags: trigger, profile, permission-sets

I have some accounts when a user click the button on account and create an Activity record then an Opportunity record need to be created. I tested this in fullcopy sandbox as admin and user the opportunities are created successfully, compared the code in both prod and sandbox are same. checked the object permissions on profile it is having read,Create, edit are there. What would went wrong in Prod users were not able to create opportunities.

Comment: I think you are doing this through trigger? Is it active? :)

Comment: Yes, it is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your analysis was only made based on the sandbox environment check when was the last time it has been refreshed, as in the meantime the might be the case that other functionality has been added to the production environment, such as triggers workflows or permission sets which might not align with the same ones on sandbox.

As @Mr.Frodo suggested you might want to check the meta data of all the triggers as well, as you might have overlooked this.

Comment: You are right I took another sandbox which was not refreshed longtime and compared the profiles then I noticed that the obj permissions on profiles are not matching.